# How to get data from Ecto in a custom mix task

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

I want to display data from my DB through Ecto in a custom mix task. How can I get the Ecto repo in my task (or start it)?

I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.Users.List do


use Mix.Task
  use Mix.Config
  use Ecto.Repo, otp_app: :app

  @shortdoc "List active users"
  @moduledoc """
    List active users
  """
  def run(_) do
    import Ecto.Query, only: [from: 1]

    Mix.shell.info "=== Active users ==="
    query = from u in "users"
    sync = all(query)
    Enum.each(users, fn(s) -> IO.puts(u.name) end)
  end

end
```

This will give me the following output when I launch mix users.list:

```
** (ArgumentError) repo Mix.Tasks.Users.List is not started, please ensure it is part of your supervision tree
    lib/ecto/query/planner.ex:64: Ecto.Query.Planner.query_lookup/5
    lib/ecto/query/planner.ex:48: Ecto.Query.Planner.query_with_cache/6
    lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:119: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.execute/5
```

Any idea or other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Ecto 3.x:**

`ensure_started` has since been removed from Ecto. There has been a lot of confusion around this topic. See here https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/pull/2829#issuecomment-456313417 for more. José suggests to either start the app using `Mix.Task.run "app.start"` or run the repo using `MyApp.Repo.start_link(...)`.

**Ecto 2.x:**

This used to work in 2.x, but apparently `Mix.Ecto` was not considered part of the public API.

There is actually a helper module `Mix.Ecto` (https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/master/lib/mix/ecto.ex) that makes it easier to write mix tasks that use ecto:

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.Users.List do
  use Mix.Task
  import Mix.Ecto

  def run(args) do
    repos = parse_repo(args)

    Enum.each repos, fn repo ->
      Mix.shell.info "=== Active users ==="

      ensure_repo(repo, args)
      ensure_started(repo, [])
      users = repo.all(Ectotask.User)

      Enum.each(users, fn(s) -> IO.puts(s.name) end)
    end
  end
end
```

This helper gives you access to `parse_repo/1`, `ensure_repo/2`, `ensure_started/1`. `parse_repo` will let your task fit in nicely with other ecto mix tasks, for example it will let you pass -r to specify a different repo.

```
➤ mix users.list
=== Active users ===
Adam
➤ mix users.list -r Ectotask.Repo22
=== Active users ===
** (Mix) could not load Ectotask.Repo22, error: :nofile. Please pass a repo with the -r option.
```

`ensure_started` makes sure the repo is running, which you were lacking.

For guidance and inspiration, you can look at how other ecto mix tasks are implemented at https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/tree/master/lib/mix/tasks

Comment: Thank you. This was what I was missing ! !

Comment: The arity of `ensure_started` has been changed from 1 to 2 since Ecto 2.0. The second argument is a keyword list. We should change the line `ensure_started(repo)` to `ensure_started(repo, [])`.

Comment: WARNING: You should not `import Mix.Ecto` because it is a private API and is now broken in Ecto 3.0: https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/issues/1586#issuecomment-233301683

Comment: @JasonAxelson thanks for pointing this out! I have updated my answer to address ecto 3.0

Answer (score 12):

As addition to `Jason Harrelson`'s answer: it's also necessary to start `Postgrex` and `Ecto`.

```
[:postgrex, :ecto]
|> Enum.each(&Application.ensure_all_started/1)

MyApp.Repo.start_link
```

UPDATE:

Another approach is to use mix task to start application:

```
Mix.Task.run "app.start", []
```

Comment: I think your original approach is more explicit, and therefore more correct, even though it takes slightly more code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure the repo is started prior to using it

```
MyApp.Repo.start_link
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found another solution when working with Phoenix. I created a new file in `priv/repo` with :

```
defmodule Users.List do
  def run() do
    Mix.shell.info "=== Active users ==="

    users = App.Repo.all(App.User)
    Enum.each(users, fn(s) ->
      Mix.shell.info("#{s.name}")
    end)
  end
end
Users.List.run
```

Then I run it with `mix run priv/repo/users.list.exs` from my project root.