# Use Ecto in a mix task

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

In a Phoenix Framework application I have a model `Product` with the field `name`. I want to create a mix task which lists all product names.

In Ruby on Rails this would be the code to solve the problem:

```
namespace :list do
  desc "List all products"
  task products: :environment do
    Product.all.each do |product|
      puts product.name
    end
  end
end
```

In Phoenix I can't even get the list of all products from the database. Here is the task code:

**lib/mix/tasks/list.product.ex**

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.List.Product do                                    
  use Mix.Task
  import Mix.Ecto
  alias App.Repo
  alias App.Product

  def run(_args) do
    products = Repo.all(Product)
  end
end
```

When I run this task I get this error message:

```
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Ecto.Queryable.__using__/1 
is undefined or private
```

What do I have to do to fetch all products from the database in this mix task?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `App.Product` instead of `Product`?

Comment: I updated the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get data from Ecto in a custom mix task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38225406/how-to-get-data-from-ecto-in-a-custom-mix-task)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hard way:

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.MyTask do
  use Mix.Task
  import Ecto.Query
  alias MyApp.Repo

  @start_apps [
    :postgrex,
    :ecto,
    :ecto_sql
  ]

  @repos Application.get_env(:my_app, :ecto_repos, [])

  def run(args) do
    start_services()

    # Run Ecto...

    stop_services()
  end

  defp start_services do
    Enum.each(@start_apps, &Application.ensure_all_started/1)
    Enum.each(@repos, & &1.start_link(pool_size: 2))
  end

  defp stop_services do
    :init.stop()
  end
end
```

or the easy way ;)

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.MyTask do
  use Mix.Task
  import Ecto.Query
  alias MyApp.Repo

  def run(args) do
    Mix.Task.run("app.start")
    # Run Ecto...
  end
end
```

- https://gist.github.com/hipertracker/a2ae2c7adf1fdd78b45712abeade7fe3
- https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery/blob/master/docs/guides/running_migrations.md

Answer (score 6):

Add `ensure_started(Repo, [])` at the top of your `run` method. You may also want to `import Ecto.Query` for some query forms.

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.List.Product do                                    
  use Mix.Task
  import Mix.Ecto
  import Ecto.Query
  alias App.Repo
  alias App.Product

  def run(_args) do
    ensure_started(Repo, [])
    products = Repo.all(Product)
  end
end
```

Comment: It does not work in Phoenix 1.4 "undefined function ensure_started/2"

Comment: @hipertracker use this. `Mix.Task.run("app.start", [])`