# Ecto 3 - Start Repo in custom CLI task

Tags: elixir, ecto

If you need access to DB for you mix task - you needed to start your ecto repo manually. While we worked with ecto 2 we had `ensure_started` function.

So custom CLI task with ecto 2 looks like

```
defmodule App.Task do
  use Mix.Task
  import Mix.Ecto

  def run(args) do
    repos = parse_repo(args)

    Enum.each repos, fn repo ->
      ensure_repo(repo, args)
      ensure_started(repo, []) # was deleted from ecto 3
```

`ensure_started` has been deleted from ecto 3. I tried a few approaches but they didn't work for me. Does anybody know a workaround for ecto 3?

**Updated**

as @starbelly mentioned `ensure_started` has migrated to `Mix.EctoSQL` so we need to add extra `import Mix.EctoSQL` to make it work

```
defmodule App.Cli.Task do
  import Mix.Ecto
  import Mix.EctoSQL

  def start_ecto do
    repos = parse_repo([])

    Enum.each(repos, fn repo ->
      ensure_repo(repo, [])
      {:ok, _pid, _apps} = ensure_started(repo, [])
    end)
  end
end
```

Comment: Would not [`Application.ensure_all_started/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Application.html#ensure_all_started/2) help? Like `Application.ensure_all_started(Ecto)`?

Comment: I tried it but no luck

{:ok, apps} = Application.ensure_all_started(:ecto_sql)
IO.inpsect apps
[:telemetry, :connection, :db_connection, :decimal, :ecto, :ecto_sql]

But as soon as I need to make a query 


** (RuntimeError) could not lookup Smd.Repo because it was not started or it does not exist
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/registry.ex:18: Ecto.Repo.Registry.lookup/1
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:131: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.execute/4
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:18: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.all/3
    lib/smd/app/search/sync_es.ex:76: Mix.Tasks.App.SyncEs.sync_all_pages/4

Answer (score 3):

The function you're trying to import and call has been moved into ecto_sql. You should `import Mix.EctoSQL` for `ensure_started/2`

Example:

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.Friends.Hello do
  use Mix.Task
  import Mix.Ecto
  import Mix.EctoSQL

  def run(args) do
    repos = parse_repo(args)

    Enum.each(repos, fn repo ->
      ensure_repo(repo, args)
      {:ok, _pid, _apps} = ensure_started(repo, [])
      Friends.Repo.all(Friends.Person)
    end)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

None of these approaches will work anymore in the latest version of ecto_sql (3.1.2) because `Mix.EctoSQL.ensure_started/2` was a private function, not meant for use outside of Ecto.

[As per Jose](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/issues/1586#issuecomment-233301683), the correct approach is to use

```
Mix.Task.run("app.start")
```

So the example @starbelly shared would be modified to be

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.Friends.Hello do
  use Mix.Task

  def run(args) do
    Mix.Task.run("app.start")
    repos = parse_repo(args)

    Enum.each(repos, fn repo ->
      repo.all(Friends.Person)
    end)
  end
end
```

The big drawback to this approach is it will start your entire application, including any background processes you have. As a result, you may need to modify your `application.ex` file to not start those if started by a mix task.

Comment: how would you achieve that ? (modifying application.ex to not start something is started by a mix task)

Comment: @RobinKomiwes there are a few ways to do it, but one of the simplest would be to do something like `Application.put_env(:your_app_name, :process_type, :mix_task)` at the top of your `run` function in the mix task. Then in your `application.ex` file, you could limit the processes you tell the `Supervisor` to start up to only include the `Repo` process based on that `:process_type` value

Answer (score 2):

As Dennis pointed out `Mix.EctoSQL.ensure_started/2` is a private function since ecto_sql 3.1.2, so we can't use it anymore.

Assuming you have an OTP application defined, which this mix task is part of, what you could do is

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.Friends.Hello do
  use Mix.Task

  def run(args) do
    {:ok, _started} = Application.ensure_all_started(:your_otp_app_name)
    repos = parse_repo(args)

    Enum.each(repos, fn repo ->
      repo.all(Friends.Person)
    end)
  end
end
```

Essentially start the whole OTP application, so that all the dependencies (including the repos) would be started as well.

Answer (score 1):

For Ecto 3.x use `Repo.start_link()` or Mix.Task.run('app.start')

This question/answer might help.
[How to get data from Ecto in a custom mix task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38225406/how-to-get-data-from-ecto-in-a-custom-mix-task)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Recommended by whom?

Comment: added the reference @Andrew. Should've included earlier. (as per Jose Valim)